# HTML: Ponto âncora - o que está?

Tags: html, css

Alguém me consegue dizer o motivo pelo qual o ponto âncora não está a funcionar?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Lake Tahoe </title>
<style>
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 52px;
    color: white;
}

header {
    background-color: orange;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<header id="top">
<span> Journey through the Sierra Nevada Mountains</span>
<h1>Lake Tahoe, California</h1>
</header>
<p>
Lake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California. Lake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California. ILake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California.
</p>

<p>
Lake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California. Lake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California. ILake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California.
</p>

<p>
Lake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California. Lake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California. ILake Tahoe is one of the most atractions located in California.
</p>

<footer>
<p>All rights reserved.</p>
<a href=“#top”> Back to top </a>


</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ao invés de

```
<a href=“#top”> Back to top </a>
```

Utilize

```
<a href="#top"> Back to top </a>
```

(Na sua versão original, os definidores da propriedade `href` não são simples aspas duplas, e portanto consideradas como parte do *link*.)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Pode me explicar pff qual a diferença entre os trechos de código? Parecem me ser iguais

Comment: @DavidMonteiro os caracteres `“` e `”` são diferentes de `"`. Apenas este último é reconhecido como código delimitador válido.